# Insert shell code

Tags: scanf, shellcode

I got a small question.

Say I have the following code inside a console application :

```
printf("Enter name: ");

scanf("%s", &name);
```

I would like to exploit this vulnerability and enter the following shell code (MessageboxA):

```
6A 00 68 04 21 2F 01 68 0C 21 2F 01 6A 00 FF 15 B0 20 2F 01
```

How can I enter my shell code (Hex values) through the console ?

If I enter the input as is, it treats the numbers as chars and not as hex values.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use as stdin a file with the desired content or use the echo command.

Suppose your shell code is AA BB CC DD (obviously this is not a valid shellcode):

```
echo -e "\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD" | prog
```

Comment: I do not understand, can you explain and give an example please ? I cannot change the source code ..

Comment: Create a file `input.txt` with some Hex Editor, containing these characters. Then run the console application this way: `program.exe < input.txt`

Comment: Understood, what about the echo command ? How can it help me ?

Comment: However i see that your shellcode cointains null bytes...scanf will copy until the first null byte so you have to produce a shell code without null bytes.

Comment: @MirkoBanchi: Since he mentioned `MessageBoxA`, I'm guessing this is about Windows, where that `echo` won't work.

Comment: I tried copy pasting your echo line, and unfortunately the scanf only took the word "echo" as input .. So it still does not work. I understand this is very intuitive for you, but i have never used the echo command and would like an explanation what am I doing wrong, Thanks a lot !

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know Windows very well...however maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495576/echo-e-equivalent-in-windows) could be useful.