# Reading few bytes from file and writing to text file using batch

Tags: file, vbscript, batch-file, dos

Is it possible to make batch file or vbs that read few bytes from binary file and saves them to another file as readable text? (eg read 4E 50 44 -> save NPD)

Exapmple file bin

[start of file]8bytes of rubbish
24 bytes THAT I NEED (readable text)
rest of file[eof]

Comment: [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495576/echo-e-equivalent-in-windows)

Comment: Excuse me. The 24 bytes you need are hexadecimal representations of Ascii characters using two Ascii digits from 0 to F? For example, if you TYPE your file, appear this on screen: `8bytes of rubbish4E5044etc.until48hexaDigits... rest of file`?

Comment: Linux has a `strings` utility that allows extraction of text from binaries.  See [this SuperUser thread](http://superuser.com/questions/124081/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-strings-command) for similar Windows tools.

Comment: @Aacini - I thought of that as well, but in practice it didn't work as well as I would've liked.  I tried to read "JFIF" from the header of a jpeg using a `for /f` loop and `type jpegfile`, but unfortunately `JFIF` was preceded by a null character which the `for` loop treated it as end-of-line.  I guess.  In any case, I couldn't extract any text from the header in my brief experiments.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with Frank's hex editor:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/alt.msdos.batch.nt/hexeditor/alt.msdos.batch.nt/q84l84C2Q8Q/CjBkaDIKxfcJ

with this command `cerutil  -decodehex myfile myfile.hex` you can see your file in hex , and then process it.With encodehex you can convert a hex data into text.