# Convert text to ascii code using DOS

Tags: ascii, dos

I came here looking for going the other way (opposite to the way posted in
[echo -e equivalent in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495576/echo-e-equivalent-in-windows)):

I have a text file with ASCII chars, to be converted to a text file with ASCII equivalent of the characters in the text file.

eg. a text file containing "--" to be changed to a text file containing "4545".

Anyone got dos code for this?
Thanks,

Comment: Since its a windows machine, why don't you use vbscript?

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft QBasic

```
dim character$(1):dim number%
open "inputfile" for Binary as 1
open "outputfile" for Binary as 2
while not eof(1)
get #1,,character$:put #2,,asc(character$)
'here one byte string is converted into character number
wend
close
```